# Fixed header initially overlays main content

Tags: css, position, css-position

I have a fixed header div `#header` with `position: fixed;` on my page which currently overlays the main content div `#main` *before starting to scroll*. One solution to initially move `#main` below `#header` would be to add a `margin-top` to `#main`. However, my template is responsive and the header will have different heights on different devices. Is there a way to add css to `#main` to sit 20px below `#header` independent on how high `#header` actually is?

Comment: You could use jQuery to get the height of the header when the page loads and then apply that value as a margin-top to your main. One question, if the header will have different heights on different devices are you going to be assigning a height at different widths or will the header height be defined by the sum of the heights of it's children?

Comment: The header contains a bunch of inline-blocks, so its children will begin to stack.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use z-index to overlay header and padding-top:20px for #main.

Comment: On wide screen devices the header might have a height of 10px; in this case your solution would work. But on narrow devices header children may begin to stack, increasing the header height to, say, 30px. In this case I would hide 10px of the main content.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, this is not possible in css without using margin-top (or padding-top) on the content because giving the header 'position:fixed' removes it from the flow of the document, so the page won't know about it in regards to relatively positioning any content below it.

A jQuery solution to this problem would be to calculate the height of the header on page load and add that value to the top of the main.

Here's an example of that: http://jsfiddle.net/CxqrY/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $('.header').height();
    $('.main').css('padding-top', height);
});
```

That will work when the page is loaded, but not if the orientation changes. For that you would need a resize function: http://jsfiddle.net/gSFYx/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var height = $('.header').height();
    $('.main').css('padding-top', height);
});
```